# Drupal account creation adds users into a CiviCRM group or tags them

Tags: drupal, groups, tags, user

We are trying to create a report that shows our new website members (those who have created an account) who are designated by mandatory CiviCRM profile fields that define a member type which the user selects at registration. These fields are displayed on the Drupal registration and account editing screens.

When users create an account on Drupal, a contact is either created for them in the CiviCRM, or a matching and existing CiviCRM contact record is found and updated. The custom fields already exist and are displayed on the website. What I would like to do is have the contact record be either added into a group or given a tag, which would ultimately make it easier for me to generate accurate reports about our different "members". The tag or group would be the same for all users. Something like "Users who registered for an account". Some of our contact records are created for other reasons so that's why I want to distinguish between the two.

Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.7.27

Comment: Have you checked the settings in the profile which says `Add new contacts to a Group ?` - If enabled, all contact created from the profile will be added to the selected group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using profiles for user registration than you can configure profile to add contact to a Group. This will have contacts who submits the profile added to group and then you can use filter group in in reports or search.

[image]